# pySpark: how to flatten hierarchy structure in csv file

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

We are trying to flatten rows in a csv file which have a "json-like" structure.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV20g.png)

We would like all rows with tag value LIN to have an extra column with it's corresponding value in its "parent" PER. LIN rows are "grouped" over multiple PER.

What would be a good approach ?

Simplified structure of what we are dealing with:

```
"ENV","ABC"
"HDR","Test message"
"PER",20221210
"LIN",1
"LIN",2
"PER",20221212
"LIN",1
"LIN",2
"LIN",3
"LIN",4
"PER",20221213
"LIN",1
"LIN",2
"LIN",3
"CNT",9
```

Structure we would like in our dataframe is:

```
"ENV","ABC"
"HDR","Test message"
"PER",20221210
"LIN",1,20221210
"LIN",2,20221210
"PER",20221212
"LIN",1,20221212
"LIN",2,20221212
"LIN",3,20221212
"LIN",4,20221212
"PER",20221213
"LIN",1,20221213
"LIN",2,20221213
"LIN",3,20221213
"CNT",9
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have simplified the question and supplied a simple example of the structure we are having difficulty with flattening